# Integrate ASP.NET Core OData with FluentValidation

Tags: asp.net-core, odata, fluentvalidation

I'm trying to make OData validate my models using FluentValidation. But I can't seem to find a way to tell OData to use it as it'll give me this response

```json
    {
        "error": {
            "code": "",
            "message": "The input was not valid.",
            "details": [
                {
                    "code": "",
                    "message": "The input was not valid."
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

When sending this payload

```json
    {
        "id": "",
        "name": "",
        "author": ""
    }
```

Also the `Blog` parameter in the controller post action is `null`.

I'm using

- netcoreapp3.1
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData Version="7.4.0-beta"
- FluentValidation.AspNetCore Version="9.0.0-preview3"

**Model**

```csharp
    public class Blog
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
    }
```

**Validator**

```csharp
    public class BlogValidator : AbstractValidator<Blog> {
      public BlogValidator() {
        RuleFor(x => x.Id).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(x => x.Author).NotEmpty();
      }
    }
```

**Controller**

```csharp
    [Route("odata/[controller]s")]
    public class BlogController : ODataController
    {
        private readonly MyContext _context;
    
        public BlogController(MyContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
    
        [HttpGet]
        [EnableQuery]
        public IActionResult Get() {...}
    
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] Blog blog) {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            // omitted...
        }
    }
```

**Startup**

```csharp
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
    
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<MMContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDatabase")));
            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddFluentValidation(options => options.RegisterValidatorsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
    
            // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "../frontend/dist";
            });
    
            services.AddOData();
        }
    
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
    
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            if (!env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
            }
    
            app.UseRouting();
    
            var model = EdmModelBuilder.GetEdmModel();
    
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.Select().Filter().OrderBy().Count().MaxTop(50);
                endpoints.MapODataRoute("odata", "odata", model);
            });
    
            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
                // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501
    
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "..\\frontend";
    
                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No. But haven't tried since.

Comment: didn't see the registration services.AddFluentValidation(); in Startup class 
 https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html

Comment: The default binder (provided by ASP.NET) for the `Blog` class probably intercept the issue before the validator was invoked. Try to mark properties of the class as nullable, and use `Validator` to check for a non null value.